# Multirow to combine cells

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table as shown below with all the horizontal and vertical lines. Please help.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWGkL.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question right now shows no effort and doesn't focus on a specific difficulty you're having in achieving this layout. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have so far, and mention in the question which part you're having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
    \toprule
    title 1 & title 2 \\
    \midrule
    a     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{c}} \\
    b     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    d     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{f}} \\
    e     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: For new users it may not be obvious which packages are required for this code (`booktabs` and `multirow`), so if you edit the example to make it a complete, compilable document, it would be more useful. Also, I don't think any of those `\multicolumn`s are necessary. Why not just make the column a `c` column instead of `r`?